# Can someone help me to understand how to write a trigger in dbms?

Tags: mysql, oracle11g, triggers, database-trigger

```
  Employee(eno, ename, hiredate, salary)
  Project (projID, projName, budget)
  Emp_Proj (eno, ProjID, assignedDate)
```

Write a trigger to calculate and print the difference between the old and new salary when the salary is updated.

I tried below statements in both oracle and mysql.
but error pop ups such as invalid trigger specification.
Can someone help me to clarify what is the basic common syntax for trigger in any dbms?

```
    create trigger update_salary_trig
    after insert on Employee
    for each row
    if(new.salary<>old.salary)
    new.salary=new.salary-old.salary
    print new.salary;
```

Comment: bro look it up in the manuals

Answer (score 0):

In oracle you can write it in 2 ways. Also you need to read the document carefully.[Trigger](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm)

Check below the ways to do it:

1)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_salary_trig
 AFTER INSERT ON Employee
 FOR EACH ROW  
 declare
 revised_sal number;
 begin   

    If(:new.salary <> :old.salary)  then   
     revised_sal := :new.salary - :old.salary;    
    End if;

   dbms_output.put_line(revised_sal);
  end;
```

2) Preferred

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_salary_trig
 AFTER INSERT ON Employee
 FOR EACH ROW  
 when  (new.salary <> old.salary)
 DECLARE
   sal_new number;
 begin   
  sal_new := :new.salary - :old.salary; 
   dbms_output.put_line(sal_new);
  end;
```

**Note:**

You cannot change the value of `:new.salary` directly by assigning `:new.salary  := :new.salary - :old.salary;` -- This is not allowed.